# Flash Builder 4.7 Mobile Project for IOS bug?

Tags: air, flash-builder, beta, beta-testing

I am working on an application for iPhone in Flash Builder 4.7 beta 2. I'm using Air 3.4 ( Actionscript 3.0 mobile project(target ios(develop on win))) I'm using the provided compiler. (i guess it's a new compiler)

some story:

For an animations pack i'm using swc that I pack in Flash CS6. Now, I decided to pack everything in 1 swc, for ease-of-use, and also to pack background image which is 960x640 (in PNG format). I converted it to movieclip and set linkage, but it did not show up on stage. Then I converted it in jpeg, and all went fine. I need that PNG layer because it will have a blank space with some other stuff in it(it has a window). So is it a known bug? Flash Builder 4.7 beta 2 "feature" or smth? any idea guyz?

Problem is:

In DEBUG mode(have not tested on export final build) in simulator the png background is invisible, althou i have it as an object with all parameters. if i change image to jpeg in photoshop - recompile the SWC again - i get background - PNG24/PNG8 - background invisible.

I know there might be more help on adobe forums, but they are a pain in the butt to use. + I'm a developer and a coder so i prefer stack's way of knowledge + it might help some one who is searching the web. i usually search stack first.

Comment: This should have nothing to do w/ Flash Builder; it may relate to the compiler you're using.  Are you using Flex?  Which version of Flex are you using?  Or are you using the new ACtionScript compiler included w/ Flash Builder?

Comment: Ok let me change that post a bit) you are right mister

Comment: Since this is about pre-release technology, I would recommend that you ask in a more specialized forum, like the FB 4.7 pre-release community. Sometimes, they can be quite helpful: http://forums.adobe.com/community/labs/flashbuilder4-7/

Comment: There is still some ambiguity as to which compiler you are using.  Did you create an ActionScript Mobile project (which would use the new Falcon compiler) or a Flex Mobile Project (which would use the compiler included with your version of Flex)?

Comment: i have created actionscript mobile project